# If url contains #iphone then make link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that generates links depending on choices chosen but I want it to generate a link based on a string in the url. How do I generate a link, with the string in the javascript, from the url if it contains #iPhone?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/12/#iphone

```
if (q1 == document.location.href.indexOf('iPhone') > -1 ) {       
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<BR/><BR/>
        <img id=create style=cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; type=img 
        value=Next src='http://fairdash.com/Next-Button.png' 
        href='http://fairdash.com' 
        onclick=\"location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?
        q1=Windowsphone&x=69&y=9';return false\"></img>";
        }
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: How do I generate a link, with the string in the javascript, from the url if it contains #iPhone? @RajeshDhiman

Comment: Does above code gives any error?

Comment: @RajeshDhiman It doesn't work form me

Comment: Why did nobody try `console.log(window.location)` on those fiddles? You would see that you don't get the hash tag at all! Just create an old good html file and test it in your browser the old way. Jsfiddle doesn't solve every problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var url = window.location.hash; // retrieve current hash value (fragment identifier)
if(url.indexOf('iPhone') != -1){ // do the following if URL's hash contains "iPhone"
    document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<BR/><BR/>
       <img id=create style=cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; type=img 
       value=Next src='http://fairdash.com/Next-Button.png' 
       href='http://fairdash.com' 
       onclick=\"location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?
       q1=Windowsphone&x=69&y=9';return false\"></img>";
}
```

**EDIT**:

From the further [discussions](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48463/discussion-between-chridam-and-user2680614) this should suffice, using jQuery:

**HTML**:

```
<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>
    <div id="linkdiv">        
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var url = "http://fairdash.com/?q1=Windowsphone&x=69&y=9";
var nextLink = "<a href='" + url + "' class='select' style='cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;'>Next</a>";

var hash = window.location.hash; // retrieve current hash value (fragment identifier)
if (hash.indexOf('iPhone') != -1)
{
    $("#linkdiv").append(nextLink);
}
```

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/4/ | The button doesn't seem to appear when load the page containing 'iPhone'. Here's the string that I have ?q1=AppleiPhone&x=103&y=13

Comment: Your query string `?q1=AppleiPhone&x=103&y=13` does not contain the `#` fragment that's why it's not loading the button.

Comment: I included, ?q1=Apple#iPhone&x=103&y=13, the hashtag and the button is still not appearing.

Comment: I've also changed a few things within the code to improve it but I need your help to spot the mistake

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes made so that I can have a look?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/12/#iphone | There's the updated fiddle. I've added #iphone to show you that the button doesn't appear.

Comment: Could you possibly tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's all updated to your liking in the fiddle above but no luck.

Comment: Sure, one other thing, does the solution have to be strictly Javascript without any libraries e.g jQuery?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48463/discussion-between-chridam-and-user2680614)

Comment: please invite me to a chat when your available

Answer (score 3):

To get the hash tag value use:

```
if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "iPhone") {
//your code here
} else {
// Fragment doesn't exist
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have that mostly http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/4/. Is there any reason why the button doesn't appear when the page loads with the string: ?q1=AppleiPhone&x=103&y=13 ?

Comment: @user2680614 `window.location.hash` is just what is after (and including) the `#`

Comment: @Skwal I included a fiddle with the #iphone included in the url and I'm still having no luck. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/13/#iphone

Comment: @coder29 I update the fiddle to your code and still no luck jsfiddle.net/SDq4P/13/#iphone